# Edit .htaccess so that homepage of Laravel site mirrors homepage blog

Tags: htaccess, apache, subdomain, mirror

I have a Laravel site at example.com and a WordPress site at blog.example.com.

Everything works well except that I'd love to have the root (index page) of example.com show (but not redirect to) the root of blog.example.com.

My Laravel `.htaccess` file is below.

**How can I change this (or what else should I do if not editing `.htaccess`) so that the homepage of my Laravel site mirrors the homepage of my blog?**

Both sites are hosted on the same Cloudways server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #--------
    # remove www subdomain (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270281/470749)
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    #--------

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are the two set up in the same virtual server?  If they are in different virtual servers you may have to use a proxy directive.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller They are two different "applications" on Cloudways, so yes, I think that means they are two virtual servers. I see them as two folders on the Cloudways server. Do you mean `mod_proxy`? (Where can I read about the "proxy directive" that you mention?) Thanks. P.S. Cloudways (my server provider) won't allow `mod_proxy` and will not let me edit Apache virtual hosts. But even if that's what you mean, I'd be curious to hear how I *would* be able to accomplish my goal using that. Because maybe I'd switch to a new host that allows it. Thanks!

Comment: Proxy can also be used through mod_rewrite with the `[P]` flag.   You could probably also code the proxy using PHP within Laravel.